# Using splat to pass and receive function arguments with an associative array

Tags: php

If I do this:

```
function myfunc(mixed ...$var) {
  dump($var);
}

$param = [
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2,
];
myfunc(...$param);
```

Then the output is:

```
^ array:2 [
  "one" => 1
  "two" => 2
]
```

It's useful that the array keys are preserved, but I don't see anything about this in the documentation at https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php.

What's happening here? Is it documented behaviour that's by design, or a quirk that could vanish in a future version of PHP?

Comment: Call your function like this `myfunc($param, 'A', 'B');` and then look at the var_dump

Comment: What outcome were you expecting instead, and why?

Comment: @RiggsFolly the $param array ends up nested at key 0 when I do that.

Comment: @ADyson I don't know!

Comment: @RiggsFolly at the error message you mean ;) That's quite a helpful error message tho, in order to understand how it works. I least it helped me to untangle this mess.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Hmm, no I dont get an error if I call `myfunc($param, 'A', 'B');` Which error message do you get?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  [Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking](https://3v4l.org/bv2m2)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Ahh right, but if you look I didnt unpack the first array argument, I was suggesting the OP may understand more about what was going on if they ran it like that and looked at what was being passed :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense No sweat :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 concepts here, don't be confused:

1. [Argument/Array unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.unpacking)

   ```
   myfunc(...$param);
   ```
2. [Variable-length argument lists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

   ```
   function myfunc(mixed ...$var)
   ```

When you call your function, the first operator unpacks the array into an argument list. Given the array is associative, it unpacks into a named argument list.

The second token groups the argument list back into array, so you get arguments of your function in the form of array. Given arguments are named, you get an associative array. You can see how it works by adding some arguments before and after $params, like

```
myfunc('positional', ...$param, named: 'value');
```

Unpacking array with string keys is not always allowed until PHP 8, with the support of [Named Arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments).

FYI if you want to search the standards of PHP, you need to search in the rfc site of PHP, here are the articles related to the question:

- [Argument Unpacking](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking)
- [Syntax for variadic functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/variadics)
- [Array unpacking with string keys](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_unpacking_string_keys)

Comment: Thank you! I had a hunch something along those lines was going on, but I couldn't work it out. Thanks!